# No application menus in awesome

Tags: awesome

Yesterday I installed awesome via an excellent [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFysY5LcD6o). Today, I'm trying to be productive;  Unfortunately, I can't find the menus to my applications: thunderbird, chromium-browser, etc.

How do I get these to appear?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the key combination `Mod4`+`r` it will display the word `Run:` on the top (besides the tags, assuming you're using a barebones configuration) then you can type the program you want to run, if it's installed you can use `Tab` key for auto-completion.

E.g.:

1. Press `Mod4`+`r`
2. Note the `Run:` dialog at the top
3. Type `thun` then press `Tab` key if installed you will see that it completes to `thunderbird` and cycle with other similar commands/applications after pressing several times the `Tab` key
4. Press `Return/Enter` key to execute the program

Another options are:

- Install `dmenu` found on package `suckless-tools` (something similar in Ubuntu?)
- Load a menu (if not loaded!) for instance in `Debian` is done like this on the `rc.lua` file under `~/.config/awesome/`:

  ```
   -- Load Debian menu entries
   require("debian.menu")

   -- {{{ Menu
   -- Create a laucher widget and a main menu
   myawesomemenu = {
       { "manual", terminal .. " -e man awesome" },
       { "edit config", editor_cmd .. " " .. awesome.conffile },
       { "restart", awesome.restart },
       { "quit", awesome.quit }
   }

   mymainmenu = awful.menu({ items = { { "awesome", myawesomemenu, beautiful.awesome_icon },
                                       { "Debian", debian.menu.Debian_menu.Debian },
                                       { "open terminal", terminal }
                                     }
                          })


   mylauncher = awful.widget.launcher({ image = image(beautiful.awesome_icon),
                                        menu = mymainmenu })
  ```

Of course the file `/etc/xdg/awesome/debian/menu.lua` must exist or something similar, you can create your own.

Answer (score 0):

awesome includes menubar. By default, pressing Mod+p will open a dmenu-like applications menu at the top of the screen.